Как прописать выключение Програм и служб с помощью .bat файла, и что делать если программа не закрывается из-за отказа в доступе
@echo off
timeout /t 20 /nobreak >nul
:begin
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im amdow.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im AMDRSServ.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im AMDRSSrcExt.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im atieclxx.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im AMDRSSrcExt.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
taskkill /f /im RadeonSoftware.exe
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >nul
goto :begin

Некоторые процессы не закрываются из-за отказа в доступе.

Как сделать так, чтобы Выбранные мною Службы и Процессы закрывались,и происходила проверка чтобы эти процессы при их повторном открытии снова закрывались, и так чтобы не было видно эту командную строку работы этого батника?
Как предоставить доступ в те процессы, которые не хотят закрываться этим Кодом?

